# Getting ems size of a string in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add ellipses to words that exceed 11 ems in an Android textview (instead of having words >11ems wordwrap mid-word) while the rest of the text continues on the next line.

I.E

|Reallylongwordgoeshe...|
|and the rest of the   |
|text goes here.     |

I've decide to just calculate the ems size of each tokenized string, but I'm unsure of how to do that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know the Android API, but you need to get the em width from the font, and the bounding box of the string from the text view.

Comment: Have you tried TextView's `ellipsize` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following in the android dev references helped me:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html
especially if you look at the documentation for the following:
void performFiltering (CharSequence text, 
                int start, 
                int end, 
                int keyCode)